# Objects override each other

Tags: java, object, extends

I have the class `GameObject`:

```
public class GameObject{

    private Coordinate coordinates;

    public GameObject(){
        coordinates = new Coordinate();
    }

    public void setCoordinates(int x, int y){
        coordinates.x = x;
        coordinates.y = y;
    }

    //More methods here   
}

public class Coordinate{

    public int x, y;

    public Coordinate(){

    }

    public Coordinate(int x, int y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public void setCoordinate(int x, int y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
```

And two classes `Champion` and `Spell`:

```
public class Spell extends GameObject{
    //Some methods
}

public class Champion extends GameObject{
    //Some methods
    public Spell fireBall = new Spell();
}
```

And in my `main` class:

`Champion character = new Champion();`

If I call `character.setCoordinates(200, 300);` (just random numbers), the character goes to these exact coordinates. But the `Spell fireBall` also goes to `(200, 300)`. So the `coordinates` in `Spell` are overriden by the `setCoordinates(int x, int y)` call to `character`. How is this possible?

**TL;DR** - Two classes from `GameObject`, `Spell extends GameObject` and `Champion extends GameObject`, override eachother `coordinates`. Why?

For full source code:
[`GameObject.java`](https://github.com/ikhebgeenaccount/SideScroller/blob/master/SideScroller/src/main/game/object/GameObject.java)
[`Spell.java`](https://github.com/ikhebgeenaccount/SideScroller/blob/master/SideScroller/src/main/game/object/spell/Spell.java)
[`Champion.java`](https://github.com/ikhebgeenaccount/SideScroller/blob/master/SideScroller/src/main/game/object/champion/Champion.java)
[`Coordinate.java`](https://github.com/ikhebgeenaccount/SideScroller/blob/master/SideScroller/src/main/game/coordinate/Coordinate.java)

Comment: Because there's only one instance of Coordinates?

Comment: Where do you create the instance of ``coordinates``?

Comment: Are the corordinates static variables?

Comment: What do you mean that they override each other? A `Spell` object and a `Champion` object should each have their own instances of `Coordinate` and will not share them. You haven't shown a constructor for `GameObject`, but the `coordinates` field should be initialized there for each object.

Comment: Added declaration of `coordinates`. I thought as well that `Spell` and `Champion` objects each their own `Coordinate` had, and that is the case. But somehow they end up being the same value after `setCoordinates()`. I think this might has to do with the fact that they are both extensions of `GameObject`.

Comment: That can't be the reason. Rather, it has to be in how the `coordinates` field is initialized.

Comment: @TedHopp Added declaration of `coordinates`.

Comment: I can't see if it ever causes the issue, but your method `setCoordinates(Coordinate coordinates)` is going to cause you problems. You should change the implementation to `setCoordinates(coordinates.x, coordinates.y)`

Comment: @KevinDiTraglia Added links to GitHub in question

Comment: The code you've posted isn't enough for us to point out the problem, and requiring us to follow a GitHub link in order to see the needed code is a problem for StackOverflow, in case someone looks at this question a year later and follows your link only to find you've changed everything or deleted the project.  Please consider including all the needed code in the question.  (Not the entire source, just the fragments needed to show what the problem is.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at your code in gitHub you have 2 methods:

```
//Set the coordinates for this GameObject
public void setCoordinates(int x, int y){
    this.coordinates.x = x;
    this.coordinates.y = y;
}

public void setCoordinates(Coordinate coordinates){
    this.coordinates = coordinates;
}
```

If you ever use the 2nd one, then you are sharing the same instance of Coordinates so changing one will change the other

The solution is to copy the values instead

```
public void setCoordinates(Coordinate coordinates){
    this.coordinates.x = coordinates.x;
    this.coordinates.y = coordinates.y;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that fixed it. I called `spell.fire(character.getCoordinates())`, with which I set the `coordinates` of `spell` with `setCoordinates(Coordinate coordinates)` and creating one instance, as you said. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In the class `Spell` you set the coordinates:

```
this.startCoordinates = startCoordinates;
setCoordinates(this.startCoordinates);
```

Subsequently this code

```
if (getCoordinates().x - startCoordinates.x < range) {
```

is equivalent to

```
if (getCoordinates().x - getCoordinates().x < range) {
```

because `getCoordinates()` references the same object as `startCoordinates` does.
Your setter method just sets the reference, but it does not copy the object.